# Running a separate mongoose query to check a condition and start another one

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose

I have a `findOneAndUpdate` mongoose query which is working perfectly fine. I want to use a `findById` query prior to it to check a certain condition **before** I run the `findOneAndUpdate` method and update a field.

So my solution has been to wrap the `findOneAndUpdate` method in a function and once the condition is by the `findById` query and passes,then call the function which will run the `findOneAndUpdate` query.

However when I do this I get waiting for localhost... until the browser sends a crash message. I know this must have something to do with the fact that both mongoose queries are asynchronous but I am not sure how to solve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you cannot combine your queries? If you are already checking the document via `findById` then you can merge that criteria into your `findOneAndUpdate`.